# Why isn't "witness" the third-person singular form in the example sentence?

Tags: verbs, subject-verb-inversion, third-person

The Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary gives, for the word *witness*, an example sentence as follows:

> (Original Version)
>
> Authentic Italian cooking is very healthy —— **witness** the low incidence
> of heart disease in Italy.

To me, the sentence should be rephrased as follows:

> (My Version)
>
> Authentic Italian cooking is very healthy —— **as witnessed by** the low incidence
> of heart disease in Italy.

So, I have several questions:

- What is the subject of witness in the sentence?
- Why isn't witness in the third-person singular form?
- Can we take it as an imperative sentence?

Comment: Please do not answer in comments, however trivial the question seems (although I disagree that this is). If you have an answer, write an answer.

Comment: I'd argue that *as witnessed by* would be a malapropism. A more appropriate phrase would be *as evidenced by*.

Comment: Before we get near Answers, three things:

My guess is that 'Why isn't "witness" the third-person singular form…' here means 'Why isn't "witness" in…' or 'Why doesn't "witness" take/use…' In a Question this profound, I suggest even such tiny details matter and we should not be left to guess what's what.

Then, is this about "witness" against "witnesses"?

Then, in the example, what exactly constitutes a sentence?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To witness something is to observe it. The sentence could be paraphrased

> Authentic Italian cooking is very healthy —— observe (as evidence) the low incidence of heart disease in Italy.

"Look at the low incidence .." is another, less formal paraphrase.

In many contexts "witness", "observe" and "look at" have slightly different meanings, but here they are equivalent.

Comment: BEHOLD the low incidence of heart disease in Italy!

Answer (score 61):

I think this usage is an imperative, of the suggesting type. This dictionary agrees:
[Merriam-Webster *witness*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/witness)

> verb 4b : to take note of
> our grammar—**witness our verb system**—is a marvel of flexibility, variety, and exactitude— Charlton Laird

[AHD *witness*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=witness)

> 2b b. To consider as an example.
> Often used in the imperative: *Even a widespread species can go extinct. Witness the passenger pigeon.*

If you substitute the word *note* for the word *witness* in the OP example, the meaning and the feeling of the sentence are about the same.

> Authentic Italian cooking is very healthy —— **note** the low incidence of heart disease in Italy.

One might interpret the usage differently, as if it were a subjunctive form, followed by its subject. :
*-witness the low incidence of heart disease*  =
*-[let] the low incidence of heart disease [be] witness*

Or one might call it an idiom. But in any case, the usage is valid - witness its commonness.

Comment: I think it's worth adding that not only is the original correct (using this answer's analysis) but that the OP's suggested re-phrasing is incorrect. It's the reader that's being asked to witness something; the "low incidence of heart disease" does not witness anything. If you wanted to rephrase in that way you could say something like "as suggested by...".

Comment: @Rupe "as witnessed by" is synonymous to "as evidenced by" in this context, so it's still okay. One of the meaning of witness: "be a sign or proof of (something); serve as evidence.
"the mid-1980s saw an intensification of interest in community care, as witnessed by the publication of four major reports" (4th definition in [Oxford](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/witness_2))

Comment: @Rupe: The OP’s rephrasing may be factually misleading (arguably), but it’s grammatically absolutely fine and idiomatic.

Answer (score 10):

The sentence *Authentic Italian cooking is very healthy —— witness the low incidence of heart disease in Italy.* is an example of [parataxis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parataxis): two short complete sentences that are combined without any conjunction. Without changing anything, you could actually rewrite this sentence like so:

> [*Authentic Italian cooking is very healthy.*] [*Witness the low incidence of heart disease in Italy.*]

The first sentence *Authentic Italian cooking is very healthy* is a normal declarative sentence, but more importantly, the second sentence *Witness the low incidence of heart disease in Italy* is indeed an imperative sentence (as @Jack-oflaherty's answer says). As such, it doesn't have a subject, and like in all English imperatives, the verb occurs in its base form without any inflectional suffix.

This answers your questions:

> 1. What is the subject of witness in the sentence?

*Authentic Italian cooking* is the subject of the first sentence *Authentic Italian cooking is very healthy*. The sentence *Witness the low incidence of heart disease in Italy* doesn't have a subject, as English imperative sentences are subjectless.

> 2. Why isn't witness in the third-person singular form?

In English, imperative sentences are not marked for number, person, or tense, but feature the verb in its bare form (here: *witness*, not *witnesses*).

> 3. Can we take it as an imperative sentence?

Yes, absolutely – but only the second part *witness the low incidence of heart disease in Italy*, not the first part *Authentic Italian cooking is very healthy*. This is a declarative sentence.

By the way, your rephrasing changes the grammatical structure from parataxis to [hypotaxis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypotaxis), or more conventionally, to a complex sentence with a subordinate clause:

> [*Authentic Italian cooking is very healthy* [*as witnessed by the low incidence of heart disease in Italy*] ].

This type of subordinate clause (sometimes called passive-participle clauses) is also subjectless, and it uses the past participle form of the verb (as seen, for instance, in the sentence *Authentic Italian cooking is very healthy as eaten by the natives in Italy*, where the past tense form *ate* would not be possible).

Comment: Hello, Schmuddi. Your explanation implies that **the definition of** parataxis is 'two short complete sentences that are combined without any conjunction'. The Wikipedia article says that parataxis is a writing style utilising such constructs.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Unfortunately, the Wikipedia article doesn't feature a definition of the linguistic use of the term. I'll see if I can find a free website with a better definition.

Comment: "*English imperative sentences are subjectless.*" Not always. "George, open the door!", "Smith, answer the phone!" "Team Five, get that test working today!" "Battalion, Halt!", "Mr Slater, put her on the starboard tack!" all are imperatives with subjects. It is treue that the subject is often omitted or implied in an imperative construction.

Comment: @DavidSiegel: That's an interesting idea. I'm not really aware of any grammar that classifies these as subjects, and I think it would be very difficult to provide formal arguments that supported that – the usual stuff like replacement by pronouns in subject case, subject-verb agreement or pre-verbal position don't really work. Do you have a reference where I can read up on that?

Comment: @Schmuddi
 I don't have any formal source at hand. Given the default Subject-verb-object order of an English sentence, it seems obvious. In "George gave me that phone" the subject is clearly "George". I think that in the roughly parallel sentence "George fix that phone" the subject is obviously  also "George".  If "Georfe isn't the subject, then what is it, grammatically?

Comment: @DavidSiegel: I don't have a convincing alternative to subject. But given that the word order isn't really fixed in your examples ("Fix that phone, George" seems as natural as "George, fix that phone", unless the context demands that you clarify the addressee first), the position argument doesn't really hold either, it seems.

Comment: @DavidSiegel: In addition, I'd expect the subject to be a 2nd person subject: Instead of your suggestion "George gave me the phone", I think a more proper equivalent to  "George, fix the phone" would be "George, I want/ask/order *you to fix the phone*" (which some grammarians would interpret as containing the infinitive clause [_you to fix the phone_] with you as the subject complement to _fix_, and this subject is obviously 2nd person.

Answer (score 2):

Change the sentence from "Authentic Italian cooking is very healthy —— witness the low incidence of heart disease in Italy" to "Authentic Italian cooking is very healthy —— look at the the low incidence of heart disease in Italy"; that should make clear what happened.

"Witness" is both a noun for a person who observed something, and a verb describing the act of observing something. In this case, "witness" is the imperative form of "to witness".

Answer (score 2):

Witness in this sentence is a command form of the verb "to witness".  You (the reader) are the subject of the verb.  The conjugation is different as a result. I think it's technically subjunctive even though the differences are less visible in English.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).