# Can an imperative sentence have a subject?

Tags: parts-of-speech, subjects, imperatives, vocatives

Can an imperative sentence have a subject?

This is a followup to [this comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/588073/why-isnt-witness-the-third-person-singular-form-in-the-example-sentence/588134?noredirect=1#comment1474896_588134).

User Schmuddi asserted that:

> English imperative sentences are subjectless.

but did not cite any source or authority.

I responded that each of the following imperative  sentences has a subject:

> - George, open the door!
> - Smith, answer the phone!
> - Team Five, get that test working today!
> - Battalion, Halt!
> - Mr Slater, put her on the starboard tack!

In each case te person or group to whom the command is addressed starts the sentence, in the usual position of a subject. In many cases a command may be unclear unless the person (or group) to whom it is addressed is clearly stated. It is therefore essential to the meaning of the sentence.

Given the default Subject-verb-object order of an English sentence, it seems obvious to me that these are subjects. In "George gave me that phone", the subject is clearly "George".  I think that in the roughly parallel sentence "George, fix that phone" the subject is obviously also "George". If "George" isn't the subject of the second sentence, then what is it?

Consider also imperatives where the addrss is more generic, such as:

> Someone, get me some water!

Does it make any sense to say that there is an implied subject "you" making the sentence:

> Someone, [you] get me some water!

I don't think so.

As Schmuddi has asked for a reference on this, I would appreciate any answers citing a source of some sort for their position on whether or not these are subjects.

Comment: There is an **implied** subject in English: you.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, "you" is implied when an explicit subject is omitted. But when an imperative is directly addressed to a specific person, isn't that person the explicit subject? Is there any authority on this? And can there be an answer, rather than a comment, please?

Comment: No, if you address a person directly, you say their name: John, go to school now!. Sorry but it's everywhere and I just can't seem to dredge up an authority on it. That person is not the subject in the grammatical sense, no.

Comment: @Lambie  I agree, one uses the name (or a title of address) directly.  But are you saying that there is an implied subject "you" in the sentence "*John, go to school now!*"? That seems very odd to me. Note my added example in the question above.

Comment: Yes, David, I am. "John, [you] go to school". John is "vocative", a direct form of address. It is not part of the grammar of the rest of the utterance. One might even argue that John and the implied you are in apposition to each other. But don't quote me.

Comment: I'd think that the addressee's placement at the beginning of the sentence is not strong evidence that it's a subject.  Consider: *John, I told you to go to school*; *George, is the door open?*; *Smith, the phone is ringing*.

Comment: David, don't trick us. Gambling, I'm shocked, shocked I tell you. Both sentences have a starting word that does not serve as subject.

Comment: A simple test for subjecthood is this: If the NP is set apart inonationally and by a comma in writing, then it's a vocative. NPs that are linked intonationally with the verb and not set apart with a comma are subjects. Thus, the NPs in your examples are all vocatives.

Comment: @DavidSiegel, Austin Can you say when it stopped being part of the definition of a sentence, that it had a subject?

Comment: Is John the object in "Fix that, John!"?

Answer (score 15):

OK, first the vocatives.
When we name the person we're addressing, the term for that is a Vocative noun phrase. For instance:

- ***Honey**, I'm home.*
- ***Mom**, you just don't understand.*
- ***Sandra**, he's coming to the wedding and that's that.*

Note that these sentences all have subjects, of first, second, and third person. Only second person is the same person as the addressee; the others aren't. So vocatives **aren't** necessarily the subjects of sentences they appear in. They're just vocatives, appearing pretty much outside the sentence structure.

So that explanation can't work for imperatives. It's true that most imperatives don't appear with subjects. That's been a problem for grammarians for a long time, and the explanation they came up with thousands of years ago is called "*You* Understood". It says that, yes, imperatives DO have a subject, and that subject is *you* (understood). That is, the subject is really *you*, second person pronoun, **BUT** (and it's a big *but*) that particular *you* is not actually there in the sentence. Except that it is in every other sense.

For instance, verb phrases like *look at ____ in the mirror* can take reflexive pronouns after *at*:

- *I look at myself/*yourself/*himself in the mirror*

but

- *You look at *myself/yourself/*himself in the mirror*.

In other words, you can tell from the reflexive pronoun what the subject is. So what reflexives do imperatives take?

- *Look at *myself/yourself/*himself in the mirror!* (2nd-person *yourself* only)

Since the reflexive pronoun depends on the subject, even when the subject isn't present, we can say with some certainty that (a) yes, imperatives have subjects, and (b) the subject of an imperative is second person (i.e, *you*). But the subject doesn't need to appear, because it's understood.

Once you come to understand that sometimes words aren't where you expect them to be, you can probly come to grips with the fact that, while every clause has a subject in English, the subjects of most infinitive, gerund, and participle clauses are also "understood". For instance, the "understood" subject of *take out the garbage* in the first sentence below is *Gloria*, while in the second it's *Bill*.

- *Bill wanted Gloria to take out the garbage.*
- *Bill promised Gloria to take out the garbage.*

Comment: Does this mean, then, that in *Everybody put your hands up!*, the imperative's subject is "you", and so "Everybody" is just a vocative and not an explicit subject?

Comment: Notice that you can add _you_: _Everybody! You put your hands up, you hear?_ But you can't add any other pronoun. The imperative's subject is always _you_, as you can tell by checking a reflexive.

Comment: @RosieF No: in that example, the subject is "everybody". We can tell it's subject because unlike vocatives it's not set apart prosodically or by punctuation. Similarly: "**Nobody** move" and "**Somebody at the front** write their name on the board".

Comment: Also good "**Somebody at the front** write your name on the board".

Comment: "Everybody" in that case sounds like's it's just "you" plural.

Comment: Why is it even a problem for a long time? In many other languages we have verbs with 1st/2nd/3rd-person imperative conjugation, so why should there even be any hesitation in treating English imperatives as mostly 2nd-person imperatives?

Comment: But I agree with BillJ on the prosody distinguishing "Everybody put ..." from "Everybody, put ...". And I also agree that "nobody move" and "somebody at the front please stand up" are 3rd-person imperatives, which are rare but not non-existent in English. CC @RosieF

Comment: @JohnLawler How did this get to be about vocatives? Wasn't the Question whether imperatives had subjects?

Comment: The OQ confused vocatives with imperative subjects.

Comment: @JohnLawler Sorry to resurrect this, but I'm still a bit unclear about your position on "Nobody move!" In that sentence, is "nobody" a vocative, a subject, or something else?

Comment: I don't have a position on _Nobody move!_. It's a short fast way to say _Everybody stop moving!_, though not as fast as _Stop!_ or _Freeze!_. Why does it make a difference what you call the "subject"? This is clearly an odd and rare utterance, and there's no reason to suppose it has a subject, any more than one would expect utterances like _Oh, shit!_ or _Fuck Republicans!_ to have a subject.

Comment: Hmmm. "_**John**, don't move!_" but "_Don't **you** move!_" and "_Don't **anybody** move!_" and "_Don't **everybody** just stand there!_" and "_Don't **nobody** move, M*^$&%s_" . Those determiner-pronouny things appear in the same place as the subject pronoun *you*, and not where we find vocatives like *John*.

Comment: Quantifiers and determiners can float. So can vocatives. So can subject pronouns. So, how many rules and how do they interact?

Answer (score 6):

> Does it make any sense to say that there is an implied subject "you" making the sentence:

Yes. Here are some sources discussing the "you-understood" that include examples like the one that you cited. There is still a 'you' understood when you add an addressee. It is read as "George, (you) open the door."

Sometimes the "you" is even included. Think of a mother yelling "George, you open the door this instant or you're in big trouble!"

As Lambie mentioned in their comment, the name is in the vocative case or, in other words, is a noun of direct address, which represents a thing or person being addressed. It cannot be the subject.

https://www.thoughtco.com/imperative-sentence-grammar-1691152

https://www.dummies.com/article/academics-the-arts/language-language-arts/grammar-vocabulary/detecting-understood-verbs-243171/

https://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/imperative-sentences.html

Comment: Well done on the diligence front. :) This should quash all qualms.

Answer (score 1):

Imperative sentences tend not to have an explicit subject but will always have an implied subject. This is because every verb requires a subject that engages in the action described by the verb whether that subject is explicitly named or not.

Stylistically, imperative sentences, by dropping the subject, are shorter and this emphasises the imperative nature of the sentence. Compare:

> You do it!

to

> Do it!

Comment: ' ... every verb requires a subject that engages in the action described by the verb' Is that true with passive constructions?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Yes. For example, the ball was hit by him.

Comment: But in 'The ball was hit by him,' _The ball_ is the subject, though 'He' (Gayle? Root?) is the covert agent.

Answer (score -1):

This is changing due to personal pronouns. You/he/him/her.

There's more updated resources on imperative sentences having a sentence subject listed here:

https://grammarbrain.com/imperative-sentence/

Comment: You should explain _why_ this is changing due to personal pronouns. Since links can rot, you should include the key points from the linked page in your answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/435505)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still learning English myself. And thought the resource was helpful.